# Firebase - Following the transit data set tutorial?

Tags: firebase

I'm pretty new on Firebase, I'm trying to follow this tutorial in Firebase's documentation:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/open-data/transit.html

But I am really stuck.. Or better, I am completly lost. Nothing appears on the screen.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.firebase.com/resources/js/publicdata/transit.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Lookup all buses on line "X".
    var transitLine = "5";
    var transitRef = new Firebase("https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/ttc");
    var lineIndex = transitRef.child("routes").child(transitLine);

    lineIndex.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
        var id = snapshot.name();
        transitRef.child("routes").child(id).on("vehicles", busUpdated);
    });
    lineIndex.on("child_removed", function (snapshot) {
        var id = snapshot.name();
        transitRef.child("routes").child(id).off("vehicles", busUpdated);
    });

    function busUpdated(snapshot) {
        // Bus line "X" changed location.
        var info = snapshot.val();
        // Retrieve latitude/longitude with info.lat/info.lon.
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</body>
```

Someone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you go to this URL (https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/ttc), you will see that there is no child named `transit`. You probably are looking for `routes`. `var lineIndex = transitRef.child("routes").child(transitLine);`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this issue still remains.

Comment: You register for an event with `on("vehicles"`. I've never seen an event called `vehicles` and doubt it exists. Do you mean `child("vehicles").on("child_added"`?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tr5P7/ (outputs to JavaScript console)

Answer (score 0):

There were two mistakes in your original script:

1. You are watching the wrong top-level ref (`transit` instead of `routes`)
2. You are listening for a non-existing event (`vehicles` instead of `value`)

This code should work better:

```
// Lookup all buses on line "X".
var transitLine = "5";
var transitRef = new Firebase("https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/ttc");
var lineIndex = transitRef.child("routes").child(transitLine);

lineIndex.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    var id = snapshot.name();
    transitRef.child("vehicles").child(id).on("value", busUpdated);
});
lineIndex.on("child_removed", function (snapshot) {
    var id = snapshot.name();
    transitRef.child("vehicles").child(id).off("value", busUpdated);
});

function busUpdated(snapshot) {
    // Bus line "X" changed location.
    var info = snapshot.val();
    console.log(info);
    // Retrieve latitude/longitude with info.lat/info.lon.
}
```

A fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/tr5P7/

Comment: Thanks again Frank! I fixed these errors. But nothing happens, I believe that can be something related with the .js file from Firebase, because the Google Maps is not generated.
(https://www.firebase.com/resources/js/publicdata/transit.js)
Even I called the div #map_canvas, the screen remains as blank div: http://jsfiddle.net/tr5P7/1/

Comment: There's nothing in the code in that fiddle to add the buses to the canvas. I left that as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: Is it first error related? http://i62.tinypic.com/25kh7p2.jpg I see after your console.log() that the lat/log is working, but I don't know how to call the buses in the div =X

Comment: When posting question on Stack Overflow I recommend to keep them concrete and answerable. You initial "Why can't I get this tutorial to work? breaks down into "How can I get all vehicles near a certain point from Firebase?" and "How can I put/move a marker on my Google map?". I answered the first one and recommend you post your second question separately (but there should be plenty of examples of that around already).

Comment: I don't want to know about put or move a marker, I want only reproduces the same tutorial, that display a map: https://www.firebase.com/docs/open-data/transit.html

Comment: That example puts markers on a Google map. You can find the relevant code here: https://www.firebase.com/resources/js/publicdata/transit.js. It seems that `newBus` puts the initial marker for each bus on the map and then `animatedMoveTo` moves the marker when a new position is received for an existing bus.